# My Validation works fine but after showing ajax validation errors page will postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, postback

I dont want my page do postback after showing validation ajax error 
This is my validation class . I used a romet validation on my validation class 
I think i should set something when I use it

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\,\.\- ][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*\s+<(\w[-._\w]*\w@\w[-._\w]*\w\.\w{2,3})>$|^(\w[-._\w]*\w@\w[-._\w]*\w\.\w{2,3})$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AlibabaVersion_2.MainResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailAddressMostBeComplite")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AlibabaVersion_2.MainResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserEmailIsMandatory")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "EmailAddress", ResourceType = typeof(AlibabaVersion_2.MainResource))]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote(action: "CheckEmail",
                          controller: "Home",
                          HttpMethod = "POST",
                          ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AlibabaVersion_2.MainResource),
                           ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserEmailIsDublicate")]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
```

please help me :(

Answer (score 1):

If you use a form method as post that should work.